# any() function check for two TRUE instead of one

Tags: r, function, any

The `any()` function from base R checks whether: "Given a set of logical vectors, is at least one of the values true?"

Is there a way to use the `any()` function, but have it check whether at least TWO of the values are true instead of just one? If not, is there another function with which I could perform something like this?

Comment: IInsteadd of `any` use `sum(logical_condition) == 2` or if it s atleast `sum(logical_condition) >=2`

Comment: If it is a set of vectors then `rowSums(cbind(v1, v2, v3, ... , vn)) >=2` or `Reduce("+", list(v1, v2, .. , vn)) >= 2`

Comment: If v is a logical vector `length(which(v)) >= 2`

Comment: If v is a logical vector `sum(v) >= 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
sum(v1) >= 2
```

If there are multiple vectors, either do

```
rowSums(cbind(v1, v2, v3, ... , vn)) >=2
```

Or

```
Reduce(`+`, list(v1, v2, ..., vn)) >=2
```